# Swift Facebook SDK blank page after login

Tags: ios, swift, facebook

I am having trouble to get the Facebook Login component to resolve while using the following environment:

Swift 3.0 in Xcode 8
Facebook SDK for Swift (0.2.0)
Running on iOS 10

I've followed all the required steps to get it going ([iOS Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/quickstarts/1619016601757957/?platform=ios) and [Swift Getting Started](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/swift/login)), even the steps not mentioned in here such as adding the default AppDelegate methods as follow:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

        FacebookCore.SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: [
            .sourceApplication: application,
            ])
        return true

    }

private func application(app: UIApplication, openURL url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any]) -> Bool {
        return FacebookCore.SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: [
            .sourceApplication: app,
            ])
    }

@available(iOS 9.0, *)
private func application(application: UIApplication, openURL url: URL, sourceApplication: String?, annotation: AnyObject) -> Bool {
    return FacebookCore.SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, open: url, sourceApplication: sourceApplication, annotation: annotation)
}
```

As for the Info.plist contents, concerning the Facebook part, I assume I have all the required tags and even some others that seemed helpful to resolve the situation, found in some questions here on SO:

```
<key>CFBundleURLTypes</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>CFBundleURLSchemes</key>
            <array>
                <string>fb1619016601757957</string>
            </array>
        </dict>
    </array>
<key>FacebookAppID</key>
    <string>1619016601757957</string>
    <key>FacebookDisplayName</key>
    <string>Nossa Cidade</string>
    <key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
    <array>
        <string>fbapi</string>
        <string>fb-messenger-api</string>
        <string>fbauth2</string>
        <string>fbshareextension</string>
    </array>
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSExceptionDomains</key>
        <dict>
            <key>facebook.com</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>fbcdn.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
            <key>akamaihd.net</key>
            <dict>
                <key>NSIncludesSubdomains</key>
                <true/>
                <key>NSExceptionRequiresForwardSecrecy</key>
                <true/>
            </dict>
        </dict>
    </dict>
```

For the last and core part, super simplified, I attach the login button logic in my login controller.

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

 loginButton = LoginButton(readPermissions: [.publicProfile, .userFriends, .email])
        loginButton.center =  view.center
        loginButton.frame.origin = CGPoint(x: loginButton.frame.origin.x,y: loginBtn.frame.origin.y + 80)
        self.view.addSubview(loginButton)
       loginButton.delegate = self

}

 func loginButtonDidCompleteLogin(_ loginButton: LoginButton, result: LoginResult) {

        switch result {
        case .success(let grantedPermissions, _, let accessToken):
            print("facebook success")
            print(accessToken.authenticationToken)
            break
        case .cancelled:
            print("facebook cancelled")
            break

        case .failed(let error):
            print("facebook error")
            break
        }
}

 func loginButtonDidLogOut(_ loginButton: LoginButton) {
        print("User has logged out")
 }
```

I've gone through a lot of SO questions, Github issues, and there are some developers running into the same situation as me, without any concrete response about the possible outcome of this error. What happens in the end, is that I get a big fat LoginResult.cancelled callback, not what I intend.

The output from the console, related to this, is:

```
-canOpenURL: failed for URL: "fbauth2:/" - error: "The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -10814.)"
```

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem, which was being caused by the methods in AppDelegate in my app not getting called by Facebook when it had finished the login.

Based on the [tutorial here](http://www.zerotopointone.org/facebook-login-ios-10-3swift-3/) I think you need to change the methods in AppDelegate as follows:

```
import FacebookCore

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {

...

    return FacebookCore.SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
}

func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {

    return FacebookCore.SDKApplicationDelegate.shared.application(app, open: url, options: options)
}
```

After making this change, I found that Facebook switched back to my app after login and didn't hang on a white screen.

Comment: Turned out the function signature in appDelegate was mismatching. Take care when copying, I guess the argument name was omited , i.e (_ something) and was not being called. I know its generic, but was long time ago. Thank you anyways!